# AWS Glue connecting to RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-glue, aws-security-group

I am still starting out with AWS Glue and I am trying to connect it to my RDS MySql database.

I'm getting this error "At least one security group must open all ingress ports. To limit traffic, the source security group in your inbound rule can be restricted to the same security group ."

I made a self referencing rule in my SG and I'm still getting an error and I followed the steps in the AWS [documentation](http://I%20am%20still%20starting%20out%20with%20AWS%20Glue%20and%20I%20am%20trying%20to%20connect%20it%20to%20my%20publicly%20accessible%20MySql%20database%20hosted%20on%20RDS%20Aurora%20to%20get%20its%20data.).

**My DB is in a private subnet.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just deleted the Security Group that was attached to it and reattached and it worked.